# Trying to search the index of the certain pattern through a string, but looks like -1 always be the output #c

Tags: c

It is a program about user input text and pattern. And use a function to return the value of index of the pattern. If pattern cannot be found, return -1;For some reason I keep getting -1 for return value;

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
   int contains(const char *text,const char *pattern){
      int lengthT,lengthP,i;
      int j = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){//get the length of pattern
         if(pattern[i] == '\0'){
            lengthP = i;
            break;
         }
      }
      for(i = 0;i < 100; i++){//get the length of text
     if(text[i] == '\0'){
        lengthT = i;
        break;
     }
  }   
  for(i = 0;i < lengthT;i++){
     if(text[i] == pattern[0]){
        for(j = 1;j <= lengthP + 1;j++){

           if(text[i+j] == pattern[j]){
           if(j >= lengthP){
              return i; 
              }
              continue;
              }


        }            
     }         
     return -1; 
  }
   }

   int main(){
  const char text[100];
  const char pattern[10];
  printf("Enter the text: ");
  scanf("%s",&text);
  printf("Enter the pattern: ");
  scanf("%s",&pattern);   
  printf("Pattern %s occurs in %s at the location %d.\n",pattern,text,contains(text,pattern));
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

Comment: Thanks!!! It works! But not in every case, like abc for text, a for pattern. -1 is still the output.

Comment: ah! yes, Logic change is necessary.

Comment: [other solution](http://ideone.com/MLE1Jn)

Comment: Thanks you so much! But our professor ask us to loop through the string. But Id love to learn other method. I see how ur logic works! That is good! ^_^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have placed the `return -1;` at wrong position. It should be placed outside the for loop iterating across the text otherwise the function will directly return -1 if the first letter of text and pattern are not same.
Also, after correcting return statement, I found out that your logic was somewhat wrong.Here is code that is correct according to me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int contains(const char *text,const char *pattern){
int lengthT,lengthP,i;
  int j = 0;
  lengthP = strlen(pattern);
  lengthT = strlen(text); 
for(i = 0;i < lengthT;i++){

 if(text[i] == pattern[0]){
    printf(" f1");
    for(j = 1;j <lengthP;j++){

       if(text[i+j] == pattern[j]){
       if(pattern[j+1]== '\0'){
          return i; 
          }
          continue;
          }
    }            
 }         
 }
return -1; 
 }
int main(){
  const char text[100];
  const char pattern[10];
  printf("Enter the text: ");
  scanf("%s",&text);
  printf("Enter the pattern: ");
  scanf("%s",&pattern);   
  printf("Pattern %s occurs in %s at the location %d.\n",pattern,text,contains(text,pattern));
  return 0;
}
```